# Was bedetet quantitativ „50 Mio. Dosen impfen”?

Tags: difference

Ich glaube zu verstehen, was *„50 Mio. Dosen verimpfen”* bedeutet: man verabreicht 50 000 000 Dosen vollständig, ohne dass eine übrigbleibt. Trotzdem wäre ich nie auf die Idee gekommen, dieses Verb (sondern *impfen*) zu verwenden. Wenn man nur das so „50 Mio. Dosen impfen” (ohne ein Adverb) verwendet würde, was würde man darunter verstehen? Dass nicht alle Dosen verabreicht wurden?

Comment: Der Plural von "Dosis" ist "Dosen".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die Verben "impfen" und "verimpfen" haben unterschiedliche grammatikalische Objekte.

Bei "impfen" ist das Objekt der Empfänger der Impfung:

> Ich impfe den Hund gegen Staupe.

> Er impft die Zellkultur mit dem Erreger.

Bei "verimpfen" ist das Objekt der Impfstoff:

> Der Arzt wird heute allen Impfstoff, den wir noch haben, verimpfen. Wir müssen neuen bestellen.

Dass der Plural von "Dosis" "Dosen" lautet, hat tofro bereits angesprochen.

Comment: Dasselbe Problem besteht im Pasiv, vermute ich: *50 Mio. Dosen wurden geimpft* ist auch Unfug, stimmt? (*50 Mio. Menschen* ginge.)

Comment: @c.p. Richtig. "50 Mio. Dosen wurden geimpft" würde die Frage aufwerfen, woran die Impfstoff-Dosen erkranken könnten und wogegen man sie impfen soll ;)

Answer (score 8):

Das Akkusativobjekt bezeichnet jeweils etwas anderes.

Beim Verb [*verimpfen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verimpfen) ist es in der Regel der Impfstoff:

> Der Arzt verimpft alle Dosen<sup>1</sup>.
>
> Der Arzt hat alle Dosen verimpft.

Beim Verb [*impfen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/impfen) ist es in der Regel den Empfänger:

> Der Arzt *impft* alle Bewohner.
>
> Der Arzt *hat* alle Bewohner *geimpft*.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Der Plural von [*Dosis*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Dosis) lautet *Dosen*.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Das Problem mit dem Verb *impfen* ist, dass es nur zwei gängige Objekte hat:

- die Person, die die Impfung erhält.
- die Krankheit, gegen die der Impfstoff wirkt.

*Verimpfen* soll aber eine Aussage machen, dass der Impfstoff erfolgreich verabreicht werden konnte, adressiert also eine Dosis des Impfstoffs selbst. Und nein, meinem Verständnis nach macht *verimpfen* keine Aussage darüber, ob die kompletten Vorräte verabreicht werden konnten oder nicht, die Zahl bezieht sich aber nur auf die verabreichten.

Comment: Der letzte Satz spiegelt, glaube ich, ein Missverständnis der Frage wider, kann das sein? Der letzte Teil der Frage bezog sich ja auf "impfen", nicht auf "verimpfen".

Comment: Ich rätsle grade, wie denn "die Krankheit, gegen die der Impfstoff wirkt" zum Objekt eines Satzes werden könnte. *Wir haben heute Masern geimpft" (?)

Comment: @tofro: In *Ich impfe gegen Grippe*,  ist *gegen Grippe* ein [Präpositionalobjekt](https://wortwuchs.net/grammatik/praepositionalobjekt) mit der Präposition [gegen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gegen) oder etwa nicht?

Comment: Dann sind "impfen mit einem Serum", "impfen für die Gesundheit", "impfen wegen der Menschlichkeit" und "trotz der Gefahr" auch jeweils Präpositionalobjekte, und das "nur zwei gängige Objekte" ist falsch. Mit Präpositionen machst du ein Türchen auf, durch das noch viele, viele andere Bedeutungen kommen können.